# Svelte not updating child component

Tags: svelte

I have an app with a child component.  The child component does not update when a variable in the parent changes.  The [code works fine in the Svelte "REPL"](https://svelte.dev/repl/60a41256a2b949f88859e2d2dd0e1292?version=3.29.0).  I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas to help debug this.

Using Svelte version 3.29.0

Project structure:
App.svelte

```
<script>
    import Nested from "./Nested.svelte"

    const mouse_move = v => () => {
        selected_index = v
        console.log(selected_index)
    }

    let selected_index = 1;
</script>
{selected_index}
<Nested name={selected_index} mouseenter={mouse_move("here")} mouseleave={mouse_move("gone")}/>
```

Nested.svelte

```
<script>
    export let name = "Ready";
    export let mouseenter = () => {};
    export let mouseleave = () => {};
</script>

<h1 on:mouseenter={mouseenter} on:mouseleave={mouseleave}>Hello {name}!</h1>
```

Hovering over the `h1` text causes `selected_index` to change from `1` to `here`.  That is rendered by `{selected_index}` but the `Nested` element remains unchanged on my localhost version but changes fine in the Svelte "REPL".

Any thoughts on what / how to debug would be appreciated.

** edit **

**When I built it for production and serve locally it works fine**.  Tried the following things and none of them worked:

- deleted all node_modules and reinstalling
- running in incognito
- running in different browsers

Comment: Your code works. (tried with svelte 3.29.0, 3.30.0) https://i.imgur.com/M7xfwZV.png

Comment: maybe bundle.js was being served from cache, for example a service worker

Answer (score 2):

*bind the name*

```
<Nested bind:name={selected_index} mouseenter={mouse_move("here")} mouseleave={mouse_move("gone")}/>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  Could you explain why that works / what is going on in more detail please?

Comment: the 'bind' keyword makes it a 2 way link, the attribute style is a single way link from the top element downwards. I've made a basic example to highlight this: https://svelte.dev/repl/1776a289c22b457287e55d061a55c84c?version=3.38.3

Comment: How does this solve the problem? If the data is only passed from the parent to the child, the binding should make no change, as it would only introduce additional (unnecessary) reactivity in the reverse direction from child to parent.